# Modular representation theory: central idempotents in $\mathbb{Z}_p[G]$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $p$ be a prime dividing the order of $G$. Let $\chi$ be a $\mathbb{C}_p$-valued irreducible character of $G$ and let $e_{\chi} = |G|^{-1}\chi(1)\sum_{g \in G} \chi(g^{-1})g$ be the associated primitive central idempotent in $\mathbb{C}_p[G]$. Let $\mathbb{Q}_{p}(\chi)=\mathbb{Q}_p(\chi(g) : g \in G)$ be the character field. Let $H=\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb {Q}_{p}(\chi)/\mathbb{Q}_p)$ and let $e=\sum_{h \in H} e_{\chi^h}$ ($H$ acts on characters in the usual way.) Then $e$ is a central primitive idempotent of $\mathbb{Q}_p[G]$. Let $v_p$ denote the usual $p$-adic valuation.

Claim: $v_p(|G|)=v_p(\chi(1))$ if and only if
$e \in \mathbb{Z}_p[G]$ and $e\mathbb{Z}_p[G]$ is a maximal $\mathbb{Z}_p$-order.

If $v_p(|G|)=v_p(\chi(1))$ then it is clear that $e \in \mathbb{Z}_p[G]$. That $e\mathbb{Z}_p[G]$ is a maximal $\mathbb{Z}_p$-order follows from Jacobinski's formula for the central conductor of $\mathbb{Z}_p[G]$ in a maximal order (see Curtis-Reiner, Methods of representation theory, vol 1 section 27).

For the converse, I can prove the claim for $p$ odd again using Jacobinski's formula and some calculations of the different of the extension $\mathbb{Q}_p(\chi)/\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Question: can anyone provide a proof of counterexample for the missing part for $p=2$?

Here is a related claim that would prove the claim and make everything much simpler if true:
If $e \in \mathbb{Z}_p[G]$ then $\mathbb{Q}_p(\chi)/\mathbb{Q}_p$ is unramified (i.e. $\mathbb{Q}_p(\chi) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_n)$ for some $n$ relatively prime to $p$).

Also, maybe I can drop the maximal order part of the claim altogether?

I have a reasonable knowledge of ordinary representation theory but have only really started to look at modular representation theory in the past few days. I know that this is related to "blocks of defect zero", but in the books I have looked at (Serre, Curtis-Reiner) it is assumed that the ground field is "sufficiently large", which doesn't really help me. But I suspect this is an easy problem for someone who knows the subject well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDIT: There is a MUCH simpler proof than my first one, which I found after looking up the proof of (90.4) in Curtis-Reiner (Rep. Th. of finite groups...) mentioned by Florian Eisele in the comments:
The central idempotent $e\in \mathbb{Z}_p[G]$ is supported on $p$-regular elements. (By the way, a quite elementary proof of this fact can be given using the ideas in a paper of M. Leitz ([Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 128 (2000), no. 11, 3149–3152](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-00-05422-8), [MR1676316](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1676316)), see also Külshammers [paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S1446788700034881) cited at the end.)
Since 
$$ e = \frac{\chi(1)}{|G|}\sum_{h\in H}\sum_{g\in G} \chi(g^{-1})^h g, $$
it follows that the character $\beta= \sum_{h\in H} \chi^h$ vanishes on $p$-singular elements. Let $P$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. Then $\beta$ vanishes on $P\setminus 1 $, so
the multiplicity of the trivial character of $P$ in the restriction $\beta_P$ is 
$$ (\beta_P, 1_P) = \frac{\beta(1)}{|P|}= \frac{|H|\chi(1)}{|P|}. $$
On the other hand, we have
$$ (\beta_P,1_P) = \sum_{h\in H} (\chi^h_P,1_P)= |H|(\chi_P,1_P). $$
Thus $|P|=|G|_p$ divides $\chi(1)= |P|(\chi_P,1_P)$, q.e.d.

Comment: You reduce the claim of the OP to the claim that whenever you have a block $B$ such that all characters in $\textrm{Irr}(B)$ are Galois conjugates of one another, then $B$ has defect zero. In literature (specifically: Curtis-Reiner: "Rep. Theory of fin. grps. and ass. alg." Theorem (90.4)) it is claimed that a block $B$ such that all characters in $B$ are $p$-conjugate is necessarily of defect zero. Here $p$-conjugate means "conjugate by an element of $Gal(\mathbb Q (\zeta_{|G|})/\mathbb Q(\zeta_{|G|_{p'}}))$".

Comment: (continued)
 Is it maybe possible to reduce your claim to this theorem? I believe it would suffice to show that (in your notation) $L \subseteq K\cdot \mathbb Q_p(\zeta_{|G|_p})$. This seems plausible, but I don't quite see how to show it at the moment.

Comment: @F. Landish - Thanks! I guess I first need to read a lot more on modular representation theory before I fully understand this; I'll probably ask some more questions on specific points tomorrow.

Comment: @Florian Eisele: I think one can reduce the question to this theorem. However, the ideas in that proof can be used to give a rather elementary, direct answer. So thanks for the hint!  
@Henri Johnston: Sorry, but my first attempt was too complicated. In fact, not that much modular representation theory is needed.

Comment: @F. Landish: many thanks for this - it is indeed much simpler :) The only point that I don't yet understand is how exactly we know that $e$ is supported on $p$-regular elements. In the paper of M. Leitz that you mention, he assumes that the defect is zero, which is exactly what we want to show, and I don't see how to modify this argument. But maybe I am missing something easy.

Comment: It looks like Proposition 5 of Külshammer's paper will give us that $e$ is supported on $p$-regular elements.

Comment: The fact that the support of a block idempotent is contained in the $p$-regular elements is shown in most books on modular rep' theory. However, the particular simple idea in Leitz' paper is this: he shows that $p^n$ divides $r_g$ for arbitrary $n$, where `$e= \sum_g r_g g$` and $g$ is $p$-singular, by computing $r_g$ in $e=e^m$ for `$m= |G|_p p^n$`. In Külshammer's paper, Prop. 3, the same idea is used. 

Comment: @Henri Johnston: I didn't see your last comment when I wrote mine. I think Prop. 3 applies here, together with the fact that if $e$ is central, then the coefficients of $e$ are constant on conjugacy classes. 

Comment: @F. Landish: Ah, yes; I see that this is a bit simpler than using the full power of Proposition 5.

Comment: There is a purely character theoretic proof that if chi is an irreducible character of G and with defect zero (which means that chi(1) is divisible by the full p-part of |G|), then chi(x) = 0 whenever x has order divisible by p. (This proof depends on Brauer's characterization of characters.) By an amazing result of Knorr, there is a very strong converse. If chi vanishes on every element of order p exactly, then chi has defect zero.

Comment: @Marty Isaacs: Actually, Knörr's result is even stronger: if $\sum \chi(x) =0$, where the sum runs over elements of order $p$ exactly, then $\chi$ has $p$-defect zero. Even more, it is enough to assume that the $p$-part of $\chi(1)$ is strictly smaller than the $p$-part of the above sum.  